# Multiplying valarrays of different types

Tags: c++, valarray

I am quite suprised that it's not possible to multiply two *valarrays* if one is of type **double** and second is **int**.

Why is that?

```
std::valarray<int> vali(3);
vali[0] = 0;
vali[1] = 1;
vali[2] = 2;

std::valarray<double> vald(3);
vald[0] = 0;
vald[1] = 1;
vald[2] = 2;

std::valarray<double> result(3);

result = vald * vali;
```

compiler error:

```
error C2678: binary '*' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::valarray<double>'
```

It's same for both *g++* and *msvc++* compiler.

Comment: The standard currently does not define such operator, that's all. What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: In my opinion it would be an useful feature. I believe there is a reason why c++ standard doesn't define it. I am just curious.